# LibGDX Saving progress when switching screen

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I switch the screen and still save the progress of the current game? For example I have an additional screen, when you press tab key, that shows some information about the player (attributes, stats, etc.), but when you switch the screen again to resume your game the show method is called again and you lose everything... The only method I know is that before you hide the screen to save the game in some format and load it in show but I highly doubt that this is the proper way to do it, as there would be a real performance issue when you switch the screens very fast... I need a way to keep the data from the previous screen and not initialize it every time the screen is showed. This would also apply to the skill tree and inventory which also needs to be saved for the entire game session. The filed loading from save game file format should be done only once not every time a screen changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Store it and load it.