# Screen does not save its progress when switched

Tags: android, libgdx, screen

So, this is too hard for me to explain this in short, so the title looks so creepy. Well, I am writing a small android application and i have like three screens: the main-menu one, and two in-game screens. I can switch between the last two ones with a switch button. The problem is, that when i switch back to the last screen I've been to, all its acting stuff starts again from the very beginning. I have also seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124295/libgdx-saving-progress-when-switching-screen), but i did not work for me(( So, is there any way to keep the screen rendering, while I am using the other one?

Thank you!

The first screen:

```
public class InGameScreen implements Screen {
    TinyBattles game;

    public static OrthographicCamera camera;

    public static Button switchButton1;

    public InGameScreen(TinyBattles game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Global.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Global.VIEWPORT_WIDTH*Global.actualHeight/Global.actualWidth);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();

        switchButton1 = new Button();
        switchButton1.create(10, 800, 150, 150);

        Assets.loadSwitchButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Global.cleanScreen();

        touchHandler(camera, Global.touch);

        switchButton1.act();

        switchButton1.render(Assets.buttonSwitchStateUpSprite, Assets.buttonSwitchStateDownSprite);

        Global.debugRender();
        localDebugRender();

        leaveScreen();

        Global.batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Global.actualWidth, Global.actualHeight);
        Global.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        Global.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    }

    public void localDebugRender(){
        switchButton1.debugRender();
    }

    public void touchHandler(OrthographicCamera camera, Vector3 touch){
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            touch.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touch);
            Global.finger.bounds.x = touch.x - 64;
            Global.finger.bounds.y = touch.y - 64;
        }else{
            Global.finger.bounds.x = 10000;
            Global.finger.bounds.y = 10000;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    public void leaveScreen(){
        if (switchButton1.isPressed == true){
            game.setScreen(TinyBattles.inGameVirtualScreen);
        }
    }
}
```

The second screen:

```
public class InGameVirtualScreen implements Screen {
    TinyBattles game;

    public static World world;

    public static OrthographicCamera camera;

    public static Button switchButton2;

    public static Balls balls;

    public InGameVirtualScreen(TinyBattles game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Global.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Global.VIEWPORT_WIDTH*Global.actualHeight/Global.actualWidth);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();

        switchButton2 = new Button();
        switchButton2.create(10, 800, 150, 150);

        balls = new Balls();
        Assets.loadBallSprites();
        balls.create();
        balls.setup();



    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Global.tweenManager.update(1 / 60f);
        Global.cleanScreen();

        world.step(1 / 60f, 10, 10);

        touchHandler(camera, Global.touch);

        switchButton2.act();
        balls.act();

        renderLayerOne();
        renderInterfaceLayer();
        renderDebugLayer();

        leaveScreen();

        Global.batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Global.actualWidth, Global.actualHeight);
        Global.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        Global.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    }

    public void renderLayerOne(){
        balls.render();
    }

    public void renderInterfaceLayer(){
        switchButton2.render(Assets.buttonSwitchStateUpSprite, Assets.buttonSwitchStateDownSprite);
    }

    public void renderDebugLayer(){
        Global.debugRender();
        localDebugRender();
    }

    public void localDebugRender(){
        switchButton2.debugRender();
    }

    public void touchHandler(OrthographicCamera camera, Vector3 touch){
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            touch.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touch);
            Global.finger.bounds.x = touch.x - 64;
            Global.finger.bounds.y = touch.y - 64;
        }else{
            Global.finger.bounds.x = 10000;
            Global.finger.bounds.y = 10000;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    public void leaveScreen(){
        if (switchButton2.isPressed){
            game.setScreen(TinyBattles.inGameScreen);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a `leaveScreen()` method at the bottom of the each class

Comment: Have you tried Overriding the onPause method?

Comment: Nope, isn't it the same as 'pause()'  which is an implemented method of Screen interface?

Comment: Ah, nvm, didn't noticed you were using libgdx, thought it was just regular activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all your code in each screen from `show()` to the constructor. `show()` is called every time the screen becomes the active screen, so you don't want to do initialization there.

By the way, you should never keep static references to anything that implements `Disposable`, such as `SpriteBatch`, or anything that keeps a reference to something that implements `Disposable`, such as `Button` or `Stage`. If you do, when the user backs out of your game activity and reopens it, there will be memory leaks and incorrect textures, etc.

Comment: That does works! But when i switch form screen #1 to screen #2, screen #1 pauses rendering. Thanks anyways and accepted!

Comment: The Game class only shows and renders one screen at a time. If you want different behavior you can look at the source code of Game and write your own class that is a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since I used libgdx, but it seems you are creating a new screen on each leaveScreen function.

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses) for a better approach, where when you create the Game class you create the screens as well:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {


        MainMenuScreen mainMenuScreen;
        AnotherScreen anotherScreen;


       @Override
        public void create() {
                mainMenuScreen = new MainMenuScreen(this);
                anotherScreen = new AnotherScreen(this);
                setScreen(mainMenuScreen);              
        }
 }
```

Then, you change the screens like this:

```
 public void leaveScreen(){
        if (switchButton2.isPressed){
            game.setScreen(game.anotherScreen);
        }
    }
```

As I said it's been a while, but give it a shot :)

Comment: I have the exact same in MyGdxGame class, witch btw, also extends Game/ .
`public class TinyBattles extends Game {` But tanks anyways